# MYSQL Get week of the month starting from Saturday with leading zeros

Tags: mysql, sql, date, conditional-statements

I have a pretty complex query that I need help with.
I have a table which contains `Order_ID`, `Date` and `Day`.

I need to get the week of the month `Week_No`. There are 4 key conditions for this field.

1. The week starts from Saturday and restarts at the start of every month.
2. The total length of the result should be 3 characters, so there should always be 2 leading zeros, e.g. `001`.
3. `Week_No` will always start at `001` even if there are no other entries leading up to that entry's particular `Date`.
4. `Week_No` increments by 1 at all times even if there are no orders in a particular week of the month.

To give an example of conditions 3. and 4.,

*If there are only 2 orders in the month of June, one on `2020-06-29` and one on `2020-06-11`, `Week_No` will be `002` and `001` for the former and latter respectively.*

Hopefully my table below is clear enough.

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦═════╦═════════╗
║ Order_ID ║    Date    ║ Day ║ Week_No ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬═════╬═════════╣
║       11 ║ 2020-06-25 ║ Thu ║     002 ║
║       10 ║ 2020-06-24 ║ Wed ║     002 ║
║        9 ║ 2020-06-20 ║ Sat ║     002 ║
║        8 ║ 2020-06-11 ║ Thu ║     001 ║
║        7 ║ 2020-05-31 ║ Sun ║     006 ║
║        6 ║ 2020-05-31 ║ Sun ║     006 ║
║        5 ║ 2020-05-29 ║ Fri ║     005 ║
║        4 ║ 2020-05-20 ║ Wed ║     004 ║
║        3 ║ 2020-05-14 ║ Thu ║     003 ║
║        2 ║ 2020-05-07 ║ Thu ║     002 ║
║        1 ║ 2020-05-01 ║ Fri ║     001 ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩═════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: I would suggest that you create a calendar table that has your weeks defined in it.  That would be useful for such a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you can actually do this with lead and a cumulative sum.  The logic is basically:

- Add 1 if the previous date is in the same month and there is a Saturday in between
- Start at 1 for the first date in the month.

The logic looks like this:

```
  select t.*,
         sum(case when extract(year_month from date) <> extract(year_month from prev_date) or prev_date is null
                  then 1
                  when datediff(date, prev_date) >= 7
                  then 1
                  when day = 'Fri' or
                       day = 'Thu' and prev_day not in ('Fri') or
                       day = 'Wed' and prev_day not in ('Fri', 'Thu') or
                       day = 'Tue' and prev_day not in ('Fri', 'Thu', 'Wed') or
                       day = 'Mon' and prev_day not in ('Fri', 'Thu', 'Wed', 'Tue') or
                       day = 'Sun' and prev_day not in ('Fri', 'Thu', 'Wed', 'Tue', 'Mon') 
                  then 0
                  else 1
             end) over (order by date) as week_num

  from (select t.*,
               lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date,
               lag(day) over (order by day) as prev_day
        from t
       ) t
```

Comment: How would I be able to get prev_date?

Comment: @MrSoLoDoLo . . . I don't understand.  As the query is phrased, it is actually in the result set.